# Getting Variables from a data structure and creating a matrix from those variables

Tags: matlab, data-structures

I have a data structure which has data points named `Vel1` to `Vel1520`. However, when I apply `Uorder = orderfields(MeanU_Velocity);` the variables put in the order `Vel1` `Vel10` `Vel100` `Vel1000` `Vel1001` `Vel1002` etc. Is there any way to sort the data structure such that it lists the variables from `1` to `1520` in ascending order? Regards, Jer

Comment: can you modify your data structure? If so why not use Vel0001 instead?

Comment: How can I do that? This it the code I have used to create the data structure `V_Velocity = [];
for dd = 1:38 
    ee = dd;
    for ff = 1:40
    fieldname = ['V_Velocity' num2str(dd + (ff-1)*38)];
    V_Velocity.(fieldname) = dataCOMB{1,ff}{1,ee}(1:1024,3);
    MeanV_Velocity.(fieldname) = mean(V_Velocity.(fieldname));
    end
    
end` If I amend the 'V_Velocity' part I will get the same result

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix to this is to always use the same number of digits. 0001, 0002, ..., 0010, ..., 1520

Answer (score 0):

instead of `num2str(42)`, try `sprintf('Vel%04d', 42)`. This prints formatted text to a string. `%04d` is a special code that says: fill with zeros, reserve 4 places, print an integer number. Have a look at [the documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) and look at matlabs [formatted strings tutorial](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html) for more comprehensive examples.

Comment: When I use `sprintf ` I get the following error `Error: File: Load_Files_TSR785_066D.m Line: 41 Column: 42
Unexpected MATLAB expression.`. This is the new code `U_Velocity = [];
for aa = 1:38 
    bb = aa;
    for cc = 1:40
    fieldname = sprintf('U_Velocity%04d' num2str(aa + (cc-1)*38));
    U_Velocity.(fieldname) = dataCOMB{1,cc}{1,bb}(1:1024,2);
    MeanU_Velocity.(fieldname) = mean(U_Velocity.(fieldname));
        end
    
end`

Comment: no sprintf will do the formating for you, so you must pass an int to it as the second argument (and not the result of ``num2str``). So use  ``fieldname = sprintf('U_Velocity%04d', aa + (cc-1)*38)``. The ``printf`` family of functions is really useful and powerful, so I really recommend you to have a look at that tutorial.

Comment: are you still sorting them as well? You should still do that.

Comment: Yes I am still sorting them